# Java Co-Variance

Tags: java, interface, covariance

For a project I want to provide a generic interface to resemble a workflow, like

```
public interface IWorkflow
{
    public void start();
    public void doWork();
    public void end();
}
```

For that, I have lots of implementation, like

```
public class CoffeeWorkflow implements IWorkflow  
{
    public void start() 
    {
        // setup coffee
        // prepare dishes
        // ...
    }

    public void doWork()
    {
         // drink coffee
    }

    public void end()
    { 
         // wash dishes
    }
}
```

Now I want to provide more information to those functions, like

```
public interface IWorkflowStartArgs
{}
```

And especially:

```
public class CoffeeWorkflowStartArgs implements IWorkflowArgs
```

To give it into the method

```
public interface IWorkflow
{
    public void start(IWorkflowStartArgs args);
    public void doWork();
    public void end();
}
```

respectivly:

```
public class CoffeeWorkflow implements IWorkflow  
{
    public void start(CoffeeWorkflowStartArgs args) 
    {
    }
}
```

But this does not work, as it is not recognized as implementation
of the interface.

Should I pass in an IWorkflowStartArgs and cast it inside?

Is there a better solution to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define interface like

```
interface IWorkflow<T extends IWorkflowStartArgs>
{
    public void start(T args);
    public void doWork();
    public void end();
}
```

and when you create `CoffeeWorkflow` you can create something like

```
class CoffeeWorkflow implements IWorkflow<CoffeeWorkflowStartArgs>
{

    @Override
    public void start(CoffeeWorkflowStartArgs args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doWork() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void end() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds interesting. Shall I extend it for all parameters, as I want to have those at `doWork()` and `end()`, too?

Comment: Yes ugly, but adheres to what you want :(

Comment: How can I model that, so it is not ugly?

Answer (score 2):

Java won't consider it as the specific implementation type.
Consider the following case, where you can see where the problem will occur (IF automatic mapping of implemented class in the function argument is seen valid by Java):

```
public class CoffeeWorkflow implements IWorkflow  
{
    public void start(IWorkflowStartArgs args) 
    {
      // This is what Java sees as actual implementation
    }

    public void start(CoffeeWorkflowStartArgs args) 
    {
       // This is yet again SEPARATE method with different signature
       // In case of auto-casting (if there would have been), this method would be AMBIGUOUS
    }
}
```

**The solution?**

Well use Generics as illustrated by @sanbhat

Or if you don't want to go into Generics, 
Then I think you should pass in an IWorkflowStartArgs and cast it inside as you said first,
like this way:

```
public class CoffeeWorkflow implements IWorkflow  
{
    public void start(IWorkflowStartArgs args) 
    {
        if (args instanceof CoffeeWorkflowStartArgs) {
           CoffeeWorkflowStartArgs coffeeArgs = (CoffeeWorkflowStartArgs) args;
           // ....
        }
    }

    // ....
}
```

Suppose you have another similar class TeaWorkFlow,
then again you need to check `instanceof`.
This is why Generics were mainly introduced - To avoid repeatedly checking by `instanceof`;
And to serve as a **general** model for similar pattern classes.

Comment: so my options are: have a big generic workflow OR have a check in every method. Both seem to be not very good.

Comment: Going for generics would be better. Seems difficult at first, but once you have a good grip, Generics usually reduce your code size. interface IWorkflow<T extends IWorkflowStartArgs, W extends IWorkFlowWorkArgs, E extends IWorkFlowEndArgs> { ... } Generics only looks long while declaring the *type* variables. Rest becomes too handy.

Comment: you are right. after starting with it, it feels somewhat natural, but looks ugly at first.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution using a single generic parameter, that ensures type safety. Lets use the generic parameter WorkflowType for it:

```
interface IWorkflow<T extends WorkflowType>
{
  public void start(IWorkflowStartArgs<T> args);
  public void doWork(IWorkflowWorkArgs<T> args);
  public void end(IWorkflowEndArgs<T> args);
}
```

You can now instantiate your generic parameter:

```
public class CoffeeWorkflowType extends WorkflowType {
}
```

Your CoffeeWorkflow looks like this:

```
public class Coffee implements IWorkflow<CoffeeWorkflowType> {
{
  public void start(IWorkflowStartArgs<CoffeeWorkflowType> args);
  public void doWork(IWorkflowWorkArgs<CoffeeWorkflowType> args);
  public void end(IWorkflowEndArgs<CoffeeWorkflowType> args);
}
```

and the implementations for your workflow arguments:

```
public class CoffeeWorkflowStartArgs implements IWorkflowStartArgs<CoffeeWorkflowType> { ... }
public class CoffeeWorkflowWorkArgs implements IWorkflowWorkArgs<CoffeeWorkflowType> { ... }
public class CoffeeWorkflowEndArgs implements IWorkflowEndArgs<CoffeeWorkflowType> { ... }
```

Comment: wonderful. have to think a bit about this, but already like it

Comment: the `public void start(CoffeeWorkflowStartArgs args);` part does not seem to work. It is not recognized as override and I would have to implement another override with the generic argument.

Comment: Alright, I've tested it myself and I made a mistake writing the Coffee implementation. The methods need to use `IWorkflowStartArgs<CoffeeWorkflowType>` instead of the final implementation `CoffeeWorkflowStartArgs` (same goes for the `Work` and `End`). I've updated the answer.